# XAMPP: Failed to load resource visiting an url form a smartphone (iPhone)

Tags: javascript, html, css, xampp

I have an html with some css and js on my Mac computer running XAMPP.

When i try to visit 192.168.0.108 (my ip address) from my iPhone I can see the html but it appear without any css and js.

In my inspector appear (translated with google translate):

```
Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. It is possible that you are dialing in to a server that claims to be "192.168.0.108", which could put at risk the confidentiality of your information.
```

I tried to add :80 at the end of my ip but nothing.
Could someone could help me?
Thank you!

**[SOLVED] Just add http:// before the URL**

Comment: Are you running https on the site? If so, what kind of https?

Comment: Have you tried to get the css or the js file directly by typing its URL in your browser?

Comment: I just tried to write http:// before my ip address and it works... damn....Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just add http:// before the URL